# Index over a column with only 5 distinct values - Worth it?

Tags: oracle, indexing

I have a table with a potential of up to 5.000.000 rows. One of the columns in this table is used alone in queries, but there is only 5 possible values of this column, and currently I got 10.000 rows and according to the explain plan it makes no sense to use my index on that column.

Will it ever, or shouldn't I bother with an index

Edit: This is the two explain plans at the moment 
[Without index http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/1903/noindex.png](http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/1903/noindex.png)
vs.
[With forced index via hints http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/8205/indexp.png](http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/8205/indexp.png)
The latter image I force the usage of the index with a hint.

Comment: It depends upon your queries, of course. The example gives the case where you are filtering by one criteria: `FREQUENCYID`. If you expect to have other criteria later (perhaps using a dynamic query) and will filter by them as well, then the index would make more sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on a couple of things.

Firstly, the distribution of values. If you only have five distinct values but one of them accounts for 99.9999% of rows in the table then obviously you would not want the optimiser to use the index for that value but you *might* want it to use it for the others. In some cases like this it's worth using a function-based index to ensure that you only index the values of interest and not the ones that are just taking up space.

Secondly, are there queries that can be answered using that index without accessing the table?

Note that it's not just the percentage of rows that will be accessed that matters, but the number of blocks of the table that will need to be accessed. For example if you have a table of 1000 blocks and 30 rows per block on average, and one column has 30 distinct values (each one being present in 1000 rows), then the number of blocks that need to be visited to read every row for a single value varies between 1000/30=34 (worth using an index) and 1000 (not worth using an index) depending on how the rows are distributed. this is expressed by the clustering factor of the index -- if it's value is close to the number of rows in the table then the index is less likely to be used, and if it's close to the number of blocks then it's more likely to be used.

also, you might look at index compression to see if that saves you space.

Be careful with bitmap indexes -- they are not friendly to systems where they are subject to modification by multiple sessions at the same time (eg. two people both inserting rows at the same time into the indexed table).

A more effective strategy if you do want to improve the efficieny of queries with predicates on these five values is to use partitioning, partly because of partition pruning in the query but also because of the improvement in statistics available to the optimiser when it knows that only one partition will be accessed and can use partition-level statistics instead of global statistics.

Answer (score 2):

The index will be useful in the following cases:

- When you search for infrequent `FREQUENCYID`'s. Like, only `10` of your `10,000,000` rows have `FREQUENCYID = 1` and you search for it.
- When you do not use other columns except `FREQUENCYID` in your queries. This query:

  ```
  SELECT  FREQUENCYID, COUNT(*)
  FROM    mytable
  GROUP BY
          FREQUENCYID
  ```

  will benefit from the index (actually, `INDEX FAST FULL SCAN` along with `HASH AGGREGATE` will most probably be used)
- When your table rows are large and all columns you use in the query are indexed. This way, all indexes will be joined instead of making a `FULL TABLE SCAN`. Say, this query:

  ```
  SELECT  FREQUENCYID, OTHERCOLUMN
  FROM    mytable
  WHERE   FREQUENCYID = 2
  ```

  can be performed by joining the values from the indexes on `FREQUENCYID` and `OTHERCOLUMN` on `ROWID`.

Answer (score 1):

If it is goin to increase in size as you mention

> up to 5.000.000 rows

I would recomend creating an index.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the easiest way it not to guess but actually try.

But it seems to me that you're comparing execution plans in order to find the best approach. It's not reliable. Optimizer may not have appropriate information to choose the best plan (for example, if you have a nonuniform distribution of values and haven't got histogram). Also looking at "cost" in explain plan makes no sense.

The better way is to compare logical IOs. Run SQL*Plus, say `set autotrace traceonly`, then run your query (with and without index) and compare "consistent gets" number. The less the better.

About importance of LIOs: [article by Cary Millsap](http://www.hotsos.com/e-library/abstract.php?id=7).

Answer (score 0):

Test it with typical queries, see which way is faster.

You may find that a Full Table Scan is faster on average than an Index Range Scan + Table Access by Rowid - in which case Oracle got it right.

On the other hand, perhaps there are patterns of data which for most of your queries it's better to use the index - in which case you'll probably want to add the INDEX hint.